# How to kill all processes using a given GPU?

Tags: windows-7, gpu, cuda

I use the CUDA toolkit to perform some computations on my Nvidia GPUs on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. How to kill all processes that use a given GPU? (killing all processes at once)

Comment: It can be done in Linux but see no way to do it in Windows, but is a good question.

Comment: @Moab even taskkill can't do it?

Answer (score 2):

This [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) command worked for me:

```
kill -9 $(nvidia-smi | sed -n 's/|\s*[0-9]*\s*\([0-9]*\)\d*.*/\1/p' | sort | uniq | sed '/^$/d')
```

Comment: You should add that this is a powershell command, also I have neither nvidia-smi nor sed commands so I don't know what else is required to run this.

Comment: You're right!
forgot to mention powershell command :(